# angular list only show category first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, list, angularjs-directive

suppose i have the next json file:

```
   [{'car' : 'bmw', 'type' : '318'}, 
    {'car':'bmw', type : '745'}, 
    {'car' : 'porsche', 'type' : '911'}]
```

and i want to creat a list using angular using

```
<ul><li ng-repeat="item in cars"><h4>Car:{{item.car}}</h4><h4>Type:{{item.type}}</li><ul>
```

i get a list showing:

```
Car: BMW 
Type : 318 
Car: BMW 
Type : 745 
Car: Porsche 
Type: 911
```

can i use some angular expression to not show BMW the second time, for instance some if current car = previous car do not show. so i would get a list showing

```
Car: BMW
Type: 318
Type: 745
Car: Porsche
Type: 911
```

I am getting really stuck, help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `groupBy` of `angular-filter` module

Include the angular-filter.js in your html and then do the following

Update your module

```
angular.module("myApp", ['angular.filter'])
```

Update your markup

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="(key,value) in cars | groupBy : 'car'">
     Car:{{key}}
     <h4 ng-repeat="item in value">
      Type:{{item.type}}
      </h4>
   </li>
<ul>
```

For reference - https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter

Working version - http://plnkr.co/edit/ZqRa0rZ1lh7QdcQihvXH?p=preview

Comment: For some reason I completely blanked on using angular's built-in `groupBy`.  Err, yeah.  That's pretty much what my answer is doing, but this one better fits the angular paradigm.  I'd upvote twice if I could.

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation.

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to reorganize your data at the javascript level.  If you had a dictionary keyed by `car` that contained a list of all its `type`s, it would be easier to separate them into separate lists.  Basically, I'm suggesting grouping your data by the car and appending to the list of types for that car.

So if you can make your object list look like this:

```
var data = {
    bmw: {
        name: "bmw",
        types: ["318", "745"]
    },
    porche: {
        name: "porche",
        types: ["911"]
    }
};
```

Then your HTML becomes a bit simpler:

```
<div ng-repeat="brand in data">   <!-- This is ng-repeat over the properties of an object -->
    Car: {{brand.name}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="type in brand.types">{{type}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you can change your JSON to better suit organize your form, that would be best.  Otherwise, you can use some javascript to transform the data:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.originalJson.forEach(function (obj) {
    var key = obj.car;
    if ($scope.data[key] === undefined) {
        $scope.data[key] = {
          name: key,
          types: []
        };
    }
    $scope.data[key].types.push(obj.type);
});
```

This idea works if changing the form of this data does not affect other parts of the application.  Obviously, this might not be the best option, but it certainly works for your question as is.

[Demo on plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LaLKpj3PPSnxc57xjIco?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ng-if` here like `ng-if="item.car != cars[$index-1].car"`

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl" id="add-container-access" ng->
    <input type="text" ng-model="query">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in cars|filter: query" ng-class="{'hide-list-style':!showCar}" 
        ng-init="showCar = (item.car != cars[$index-1].car)">
        <h4 ng-if="showCar">Car:{{item.car}}</h4>
        <h4>Type:{{item.type}}</h4>
      </li>
      <ul>
</div>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/8aKMxgIRXJAuVMDk1o9e?p=preview)

Comment: This only checks to see if it's not the same as the car immediately preceding it.

Comment: @wilbur so how you want it?

Comment: I believe the OP wanted it so that it would only show the car name if it has not been shown at all before. Though I just realized that he's not asking exactly what I thought he was. I also don't know if his list is sorted by car name before it is passed to angular.

Comment: @wilbur I think he is already sorted an array.he just wants to hide the multiple occurrence of `car`

Comment: Thanks alot, it is quite helpfull. Only thing is that I use a search-filter, when a start searching for instance for bmw. It does not work anymore...